# Is this raised shingle near the dormer flashing an issue?

Tags: roof

My wife noticed a raised shingle coming off the flashing of our upstairs dormer. I'm not very experienced with roof maintenance. My first reaction was that it wasn't a big deal and is probably still protecting the underlying layers. However, I figured it would be good to see if anybody online with some more experience thought differently. this particular spot is difficult to reach in my attic to look for water damage so I would like to avoid that unless somebody here thinks it is worth the effort.

[image: A raised shingle on my house.]

Comment: Wind can probably push rain/water inside/under that.  If the wind is strong enough, that will be the first to go and might weaken others around it so they blow off also.

Comment: Blow off from wind hitting this side of the house is my first thought...

Comment: If you get winds like we just saw in the UK this past week [122mph, a new record], that's a disaster waiting to happen. Wind will lift the whole lot off, from that tile, up in a wedge. [I shall now go back to trying to find where all my fence panels ended up…;)

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I'll get up there and look into it!

Comment: And do what? Throw some tar under it? I guess, if it makes you (or more importantly, her) happy. This is a non issue IMO.

Comment: @Mazura , I believe it is a non issue as well, but I am anal enough to want to get a heat gun up there and gently warm it up to get it to lay down, and while it is still warm add that little bit of sealant under it just for good measure. You know... while I am up there....

Comment: I agree with Jack with it being winter and temps in the teens in my area I would be worried ablut it cracking, not a big deal but some black Jack or other cold process tar under it and then some heat will help it to relax / lay flat and have a long service life.